# What statistical equation am I looking for?

Tags: statistics, average

Suppose you have two data sets:

Dataset $A$: $4$, $2$, $6$, $5$, $3$, $3$, $5$, $4$, $4$

Dataset $B$: $8$, $0$, $0$, $8$, $9$, $1$, $1$, $9$, $0$

Both data sets have a mean of $4$, but dataset $A$'s values center much more around the mean whereas dataset $B$'s values group around two extremes ($0$ and $1$ & $8$ and $9$)

I am looking for the statistical equation to show how closely the values related to the average. I am looking for more than just a "range" of numbers in the dataset.  Would standard deviation do the trick?

Comment: [Standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) and [Kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) may both be of help to you here.

Comment: I am looking for the statistical equivalent of a scatter plot

Comment: @Shaktal: IMHO standard deviation is more appropriate for OP than kurtosis: std.dev. corresponds to range (usually presumed from (mean - 3 std.dev) to (mean + 3 std.dev). Kurtosis is more about heaviness of the ends of the range relative to the range middle.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: This may be better as a comment perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't it look more like an answer? Your comment does, too.